# Is there a way to check for loop exhausted without any item matched in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

```
select msgbox by title and check
[Arguments]    ${title}    ${msg}
@{wins}    Get Window Handles
:FOR    ${win}    IN    @{wins}
\    Select Window    ${win}
\    ${current_win_title}    Get Title
\    run keyword if    "${current_win_title}" == "${title}"    run keywords    Element Text Should Be    contentTD    ${msg}
\    ...    AND    Exit For Loop
```

hi, I'm using SeleniumLibrary and robotframework to test a website, I need to switch to the specific window by window's title and check the element text in the window.

My question is in some situation all windows are not match the if condition in the for loop and the loop is exhausted, is there a way to check this situation and run the for loop again or dose robot framework for loop has the else part in the for loop for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean variable was the condition meet, and check after the loop its value:

```
select msgbox by title and check
[Arguments]    ${title}    ${msg}

@{wins}    Get Window Handles
${found}=    Set Variable    ${False}
:FOR    ${win}    IN    @{wins}
\    Select Window    ${win}
\    ${current_win_title}    Get Title
\    ${found}=    Set Variable If     "${current_win_title}" == "${title}"    ${True}   ${False}
\    run keyword if    ${found}    run keywords    Element Text Should Be    contentTD    ${msg}
\    ...    AND    Exit For Loop

Run Keyword If    not ${found}    Fail      The title was not found
```